# Inheritance in Java, what is this referring to?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

suppose I have 2 classes, namely A and B

```
class A {
    int n;
    public A() {
        this.n = 1;
    }
    public void compute() {
        this.n = this.n * 2;
    }
    public void print() {
        this.compute();
        System.out.println("A: " + this.n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B b = new B();
       b.print();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int n;
    public B() {
        this.n = 5;
    }
    public void compute() {
        this.n = this.n * 2;
    }
    public void print() {
       super.print();
       System.out.println("B: " + this.n);
    }
}
```

When I call b.print(), class A's print() will be called because of super.print(). In class A's print(), there's this.compute() and a statement to print this.n. It will print the value of A's n. However, it will call the compute() of class B even I specified this. Can I ask why will this happen?

Comment: You shouldn't shadow variables like `n`. And the reason it works this way is because that is how polymorphism and inheritance is designed in Java.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, so "this." only work for instance variable but not function (as the most specific version of compute() will be called) in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: `this` is a reference to the "current" object (i.e. the object the method was called on). For methods, the dispatch is dynamic, which means it selects the right method at runtime based on the actual type of the object. For fields, the dispatch is static, which means it selects the field at compiletime, based on the declared type of `this` (which inside a method in `A` is `A`).

Comment: I understand now! That's a very detailed explanation. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your instance is a `class B` object, hence if a method is overridden it will be called considering the context of the object you have instantiated.

Comment: Methods are overridden, not overwritten.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't know there was this intricacy in the language.

Comment: It is not an intricacy ... just correct terminology.  Overwrite and override are different words with different meanings ... both in regular English and in IT English.